# How to run C# Desktop Application with extension .exe in Mac OSX?

Tags: c#, macos, mono

I installed MonoFramework and I have myproject.exe file.How to run C# Desktop Application with extension .exe in Mac OSX?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You should use the following command line:

```
mono my_cool_program.exe
```

Answer (score 4):

yes this is working fine for run exe file...

open terminal ...

then  write mono on terminal  and copy exe file path and past after mono, then your exe file execute...

like

apple-pc:~ Santosh$ mono /Users/Santosh/Downloads/Myapp/bin/Debug/Myapp.exe

Answer (score 2):

I think you will have to install [Mono Runtime](http://www.mono-project.com/Mono:Runtime) on target machine.