# How can I run a visual studio project from the mac command line?

Tags: visual-studio-mac

I have a visual studio project that generates an exe file. I can run this project from within Visual Studio Community for Mac simply by clicking Run for the Release or Debug configurations.

I need to be able to do this from the command line. I've tried using [wine](https://www.winehq.org/) but it throws exceptions that I never see in VSC.

Comment: Open a terminal and run `mono your.exe`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run C# Desktop Application with extension .exe in Mac OSX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3385652/how-to-run-c-sharp-desktop-application-with-extension-exe-in-mac-osx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @Lex Li!

The solution is to open a terminal and run

```
mono <path to your app> <your app's arguments>
```